# script unable to detect java VM executable

Tags: groovy, jvm, ready-api

I use ssh commands through groovy scripts in a SOAPUI project and it works pretty well, but now, I encounter a strange problem.

I want to execute a shell and it does not work, I have in return the following :

```
1806424 This script was unable to detect the java VM executable. Please set the VM_HOME environment variable or add the 'java' to the executable PATH.  Current VM_HOME is
```

So I tried to set the VM_HOME variable to point to the jvm.dll, added it to PATH and I can check with a groovy script that it is properly detected by SOAPUI :

```
def java_home = context.expand('${#Env#VM_HOME}');
log.info java_home
```

gives me

```
Thu Jul 04 09:04:25 CEST 2019: INFO: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3
```

But still, my ssh command returns the same thing !? current VM_HOME is ''
In my testCase, two former steps launch .sh as well and they work as expected, there is only this one that fails

If I launch the script directly on my server via a terminal, it works fine.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally someone could help me (merci Pierre !) and I found the solution :
when I was echoing path directly in the server I could see

```
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/ejre1.8.0_202/bin
```

when I was echoing path through SOAP UI and ssh command I could see only

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

(I don't know if it is possible to set this path in SOAP UI settings ? If anyone knows ...)
anyway, I had to force the path to the wanted value, which can be done using the following command :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/ejre1.8.0_202/bin && <my_command>
```

this works as expected.